# Where is the best place to store user data on the web interface

Tags: next.js, cookies, local-storage, state

I'm developing a full-featured Next.js application. This is my first experience creating authorization and I want to know where is the best way to store user information on the client.

The site allows user authorization; After authorization, the client receives a jwt token from the backend, with which you can obtain information about the user.

**User information:**

```
_id: string,
username: string,
email: string,
git: string,
tags: [string],
socials: [string],
about: string,
```

Where is the best place to store this kind of information? In the local storage, making requests to the server each time, or in the global state, for example using Redux, sending only 1 request?